# Winsock send recv buffer size

Tags: mfc, winsock, winsock2, winsockets

I'm writing a MFC app to implement a client/server scenario and using Win socket for that. I can send/receive a small message e.g. "hello". Also, I tried with buffer of size 1000. However, when I increase its size further, it just hangs. Doesn't even throw any error.

Any idea about what the problem could be? Is there any restriction on the maximum size of buffer I can send/receive in winsock? I'm a newbie in this and never used winsock before.

Comment: The maximum size a TCP packet can have is 64K. Trying to send a packet with that size, will most likely cause your packet to get lost. A packet around 1000 bytes should not be a problem however. Please post some code.

Comment: I tried with 2000 bytes and it worked fine now. Didn't change the code for that. However, it fails for bigger data, say 9000 bytes. Also, when it hangs, I see "The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1bc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0)" on the output window of server app.

Comment: Got it :) there was some minor bug in my code and also, I wasn't actually receiving the data from server end. I was waiting for all data to arrive instead. Now I can receive the data, in multiple runs though.

Comment: Are you using TCP or raw sockets?  TCP does not, at app level, transfer 'packets' and so I cannot understand some of the other comments. Application buffer sizes greater than 64k are not uncommon, and will work fine.

Comment: I'm using TCP since winsock supports that. So when I was sending a big chunk of data (10000 bytes), I observed that I was able to retrieve only 9000 bytes of data at server app. And only after receiving it, I was able to retrieve the remaining 1000 bytes. Interestingly, I'm not able to reproduce the same case now. It gets me even the big chunk of data at a time which is probably what you are saying.

Comment: The fact that you receive a part of the data, then the remaining part, is covered in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16016994/218597). It's basically the way TCP works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821759/winsock-send-recv-buffer-size#comment22873372_15821759) by icabod replies this question.

"The fact that you receive a part of the data, then the remaining part, is covered in my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925158/c-winsock-recv-buffer-junk/16016994#16016994). It's basically the way TCP works. – icabod"